# React Navigation deeplinking with handled authentication

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I am encountering a problem with my authentication and React-Navigation's way of deeplinking.

I have the following navigation structure:

```
Authenticated Stack
 //screens including TrackListScreen
Unauthenticated Stack
 //login screen
```

I deeplink to the `TrackListScreen` via the `/playlist/${id}` path, which is in the Authenticated Stack.
How can I make it so, if the user isn't authenticated, basically he's in the Unathenticated stack redirect to the login first? Or check if the user is logged somehow and if not I can navigate there. The docs do not mention anything about this.

My deeplinking structure is:

```
const linking = {
    prefixes: ['appName://', 'appName.com://', APP_WEB_DOMAIN],
    config: {
      screens: {
        SignInScreen: 'login',
        UnauthenticatedStack: '',
        TrackListScreen: 'playlist/:id/' //:id gets parsed as a string, you have to specify it if you want a number.
      }
    }
  };
```

***Thanks in advance!***